# MintMenu and openSUSE

Tags: gnome, opensuse, linux-mint, gnome-panel

I've download the MintMenu rpms for openSUSE. Overall, I like it way more than the default GNOME Main Menu openSUSE provides.

But there's a few openSUSE options, like Install/Remove Software and YaST, I would like to add under MintMenu System sub itens.

Is possible to change itens in this area? If it is, how to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manually edited MintMenu python files.